# Python Magnetic field map

Tags: python, dictionary, cartopy

I am working on Satellite data in regards to the earths magnetic field. I am working in Python3 in Jupyter Notebook.
The data contains Magnetic field, longitude and latitude. I make grid 25x25 and get this map.

Here is my script

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
plt.pcolor(lon, lat, Magn, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap ='jet')
```

[The map I have now , magnetic field map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj1ka.png)

But I need to normalize data(which idk how to do) to get smooth map. As attached below.

[The map I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K45Ns.png)

Hope someone can help me )

Comment: Is this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata  what you need?

Answer (score 0):

My answer probably comes a little late, but in case anyone else wants to know, here are a few pointers:

You could start with downloading more high resolution magnetic field data. A good place is the NOAA website. There is software you can download, that can generate magnetic field (World Magnetic Model 2020) data in any resolution you need.

[NOAA: Downoad WMM 2020 software](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml)
update: there is a newer version of the website:
[NOAA: World Magnetic Model (WMM)](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/world-magnetic-model)

With their grid calculator you can genearte and download magnetic field data in any resolution over any section of the earth (or the whole globe) in any altitude and for any date.

[WMM Grid Calculator](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfgrid)

When it comes to visualization of the magnetic field, I found it easiest to first convert you data into a pandas DataFrame. You can do this directly on import:

```
df_mag = pd.read_csv('data/magdata.csv')
# Assign column names
df_mag.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'alt', 'date', 'field', 'aux']
```

I then convert the data into a pivot table:

```
mag_table = df_mag.pivot_table(values='field', index='lat', columns='lon')
```

You can then visualize the data nicely with matplotlib's imshow:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(mag_table, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
# If you want contour lines:
contours = ax.contour(mag_table, 20, colors='black', linewidths=0.3)
```

The result is a very smooth representation of earths magnetic field:

[Magnetic field of earth in 400 km altitude, based on a 1 degree grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIaUD.png)